# .NET public http listener running alongside with Apache

Tags: c#, .net, apache, network-programming, httplistener

I have a simple part of the code that creates a http listener for a specific url. Everything works perfectly, untill I turn on Xampp -  Apache Web Server. At that moment, whenever I try to run the listener, I get  *Address already in use* exeption.
I did some research and found a possible cause: I guess it won't work because Apache is listening to http port(idk if it is a proper term, it is what I got from running *lsof-i:http* command.), therefore my app cannot start the listener on http. But it is weird, since I have full url specified, so I suppose if request matches the url, Apache should stay away from it... Maybe I am wrong...
Does anyone know a solution how I could run Apache and my http listener at the same time?
Also I am running Debian 10 if it helps. Thanks in advance!

```
HttpListener listener2 = new HttpListener();
                listener2.Prefixes.Clear();
                listener2.Prefixes.Add("http://xxxx.xxxx.eu/");
                listener2.Start();
                LogWriteLine("http listener started listening to: " +listener2.Prefixes);
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        HttpListenerContext context = listener2.GetContext();
                        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                        System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
                        System.Text.Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
                        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);


                        if (!request.HasEntityBody)
                        {
                            LogWriteLine("No client data was sent with the request.");
                            Thread.Sleep(300);
                        }

                        if (request.ContentType != null)
                        {
                            LogWriteLine("Client data content type " + request.ContentType);
                        }
                        LogWriteLine("Client data content length " + request.ContentLength64);
                        LogWriteLine("Start of client data:");                     
                        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var bytes = default(byte[]);
                        using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                 request.ContentEncoding))
                        {
                            text = reader1.ReadToEnd();
                            using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                memstream.Position = 0;
                                reader1.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
                                bytes = memstream.ToArray();
                                memstream.Position = 0;
                                Console.WriteLine("memstream length: " + memstream.Length);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("bytes:" + bytes.Length); //output: bytes: 0

                        }


                        LogWriteLine("End of client data:");
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                        response.Close();
                        body.Close();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);

                }
```

Comment: Let your listener take `http://localhost:5000` instead, and then configure Apache as a reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-apache

Comment: Thank you @LexLi , I will try it. It looks like it is exactly what I need. I will report the fail/success if I remeber :)